# Difference between "undock" and "depart" (SpaceX Dragon Mission 1); when did it leave?

Tags: spacex, iss, docking, dragon-v2, return

Reading the Astronomy SE question [Did I see the dragon capsule on Friday night?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29942/7982) I thought I'd check some times.

Wikipedia's [SpX-DM1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpX-DM1) says:

```
Docking port    Harmony forward[3]
Docking date    3 March 2019 10:51 (UTC)
Undocking date  8 March 2019 7:32 (UTC)
Time docked     4 days, 20 hours, 41 minutes
```

but Wikipedia's [/Dragon_2; Orbital_flight_tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_2#Orbital_flight_tests) says:

```
Mission       SpX-DM1
Capsule       C201
Launch date   2 March 2019 (UTC)
Remarks       Uncrewed test flight of the Dragon 2 capsule; 
                  Docked 3 March 0851 UTC
                  Departed 8 March 0532 UTC
Time at ISS   4:21:17
Outcome       Success
```

**Question:** The first gives "Undocking" at 7:32 UTC but the second gives "Departed" 05:32 UTC. Are these consistent? What do "Undocking" and "Departed" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docking times also differ between the two quotes, the first one is 10:51, the second one is 8:51 (2 hours earlier, just as "departed" is 2 hours earlier than "undocking").

Undocking and departed probably mean the same thing, and the times are different only because of some errors in one of the two quotes when converting timezones from some other source.

EDIT: By the way, the correct time was 7:32 UTC, as Dragon departed (or undocked!) @ 2.32 am EST

See: [NASA Tweet](https://twitter.com/NASA/status/1103923222527979523) or [NASA Blog](https://blogs.nasa.gov/commercialcrew/2019/03/08/crew-dragon-departing-international-space-station/)

Comment: @uhoh Answer edited to add the correct undocking ("departure"!) time :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. New time zone: NTT (NASA Tweeted Time).